# mongoose / mongodb best way to calculate stats

Tags: javascript, mongodb, performance, mongoose

I have the following query`s :

```
function calculate_stats() {
         Users.count().then(function(allusers) {
                Users.count().then(function(dead_users) {
                    Users.count().then(function(banned_users) {
                        Users.count().then(function(vacation_users) {
                            Users.count().then(function(in_hotel_users) {
                                var aliveusers = allusers - dead_users - banned_users;
                                var accounts = {
                                    registred: allusers,
                                    alive: aliveusers,
                                    dead: dead_users,
                                    banned: banned_users,
                                    vacation: vacation_users,
                                    inhotel: in_hotel_users,
                                    outsidehotel: aliveusers - in_hotel_users,
                                    outsidehotelonline: 0
                                };
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });



        });
    }
```

but is really this the best way to nest them like that, to get the final result?
How would i acually proceed to get a good way to calculate the stats.

Wouldnt this be performance in-effective?

Comment: When I see many nested callback I think in hadouken. It's more readable using promise.

Comment: Could you provide example using my example code? @LucasCosta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the queries seem independent of each other, you can execute them in parallel. You can use a promise library like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)(using the Q.all method) to create a combined promise from all, or use use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) if using ES6

```
function calculate_stats() {
    var promiseArr = [
        Users.count(),
        Users.count(),
        Users.count(),
        Users.count(),
        Users.count()
    ]

    Q.all(promiseArr).then(function (results) {
        var allusers = results[0];
        var dead_users = results[1];
        // and so on

        var aliveusers = allusers - dead_users - banned_users;
        var accounts = {
            registred: allusers,
            alive: aliveusers,
            dead: dead_users,
            banned: banned_users,
            vacation: vacation_users,
            inhotel: in_hotel_users,
            outsidehotel: aliveusers - in_hotel_users,
            outsidehotelonline: 0
        };
    })

});
}
```